# Generating an SIS epidemilogical model using Python networkx

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, networkx

I have been told *networkx* library in *python* is the standard library to use for graph-theoretical applications, but I have found using it quite frustrating so far.

What I want to do is this:
Generating an SIS epidemiological network, assigning initial contact rates and recovery rates and then following the progress of the disease.

More precisely, imagine a network of *n* individuals and an adjacency matrix *A*. Values of *A* are in *[0,1]* range and are *contact rates*. This means that the *(i,j)* entry shows the probability that disease is transferred from node *i* to node *j*. Initially, each node is assigned a random label, which can be either *1* (for Infective individuals) or *0* (for Susceptible, which are the ones which have not caught the disease yet).

At each time-step, if the node has a *0* label, then with a probability equal to the maximum value of weights for incoming edges to the node, it can turn into a *1*. If the node has a  *1* label then with a probability specified by its recovery rate, it can turn into a *0*. Recovery rate is a value assigned to each node at the beginning of the simulation, and is in *[0,1]* range.

And while the network evolves in each time step, I want to display the network with each node label coloured differently.

If somebody knows of any other library in python that can do such a thing more efficiently than netwrokx, be grateful if you let me know.

Comment: I think networkx is probably a pretty good basis for this.  I've written a package based on networkx that simulates epidemic spread: https://epidemicsonnetworks.github.io/ - I haven't publicized it yet since I'm in the final stages of cleaning it.  I'm not sure how complete the support for weighted graphs is.  Also, it would allow each neighbor to possibly infect a node, not just the highest weighted neighbor (not clear to me what the biological motivation for your model would be).  A plan is to add support for visualizing the network, but it's not there yet.

Comment: and - requests for library recommendations are explicitly off-topic at SO.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what the biological motivation of just using the highest weight rather than all of them.  If you reach out to me (hunt me down online), I'll try to see if my code or a modification of it would work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Joel for your help. I have already downloaded your code and will send you an email in the next few days.

Comment: I plan to extend my previous work on SIS models with time-varying contact rates (preprint in here: arxiv.org/abs/1306.0135). In that paper, we have divided the population into groups and have taken a dynamical systems approach, not a graph theoretical approach and the issue of indivuals being in conatct with each other is not addressed expliceitly.

Comment: And to answer your question shorlty, using only the maximum weight among incoming edges was just an assumption to simplify the setup for those who want to think of it and reply. I cannot think of any biological justifications for it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is now possible with [EoN](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/).

You appear to want a discrete SIS epidemic with weighted edges.

At present this is the one common case I seem to have left out: here's the bug report I created a while ago.  The pandemic has sapped my time to work on this.
https://github.com/springer-math/Mathematics-of-Epidemics-on-Networks/issues/40

What it can do right now is discrete time SIS where each edge is equally weighted.  It can also do continuous time SIS or SIR as well as discrete time SIR where the edges may or may not be weighted.

A basic SIS simulation is:

```
import networkx as nx
import EoN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(1000,0.002)
t, S, I = EoN.basic_discrete_SIS(G, 0.6, tmax = 20)
plt.plot(t,S)
```

Comment: Thank you Joel for bringing this to my attention. I will have a look asap. I have developed a library myself to simulate deterministic compartmental models. You can find it here: https://github.com/vahid-sb/MiTepid_sim

Answer (score 0):

Do you use networkx for calculation or visualization?

There is no need to use it for calculation since your model is simple and it is easier to calculate it with matrix (vector) operations. That is suitable for numpy.

Main part in a step is calculation of probability of switching from 0 to 1. Let N be vector that for each node stores 0 or 1 depending of state. Than probability that node n switch from 0 to 1 is `numpy.amax(A[n,:] * N)`.

If you need visualization, than probably there are better libraries than networkx.